# Python Choices and input

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and I need some help with this line of code:

```
sub = float(input("Type in the name of the sub sandwhich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of."))

if sub == bacon:
    print("282 Calories, 688.4g Fat, 420mg Sodium, 1407mg Potassium, and 33.5g Protein")
```

Results after inputing:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bacon
```

Answer (score 2):

You have **two** errors in your code. You are asking the **name** of the sub sandwich, therefore you do not need to case `float(input())`, just leave it at `input()`. *Tip: If you are using python2.x, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`*

Your second error is that you are checking `if sub == bacon:`. `sub` is already defined, but `bacon` is not, so you need to surround it with quotations.

Here is your edited code:

```
sub = input("Type in the name of the sub sandwich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of:\n")

if sub == 'bacon': #'bacon' with quotations around it 
    print("282 Calories, 688.4g Fat, 420mg Sodium, 1407mg Potassium, and 33.5g Protein")
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
Type in the name of the sub sandwich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of:
bacon
282 Calories, 688.4g Fat, 420mg Sodium, 1407mg Potassium, and 33.5g Protein
bash-3.2$
```

If you are looking to add more possible subs, I would suggest using a dictionary, like the following:

```
subs = {'bacon':["282", "688.4", "420", "1407", "33.5"], 'ham':["192", "555.2", "340", "1802", "44.3"], "cheese":["123", "558.9", "150", "1230", "12.5"]}

sub = input("Type in the name of the sub sandwich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of:\n")

arr = subs[sub]
print("%s Calories, %sg Fat, %smg Sodium, %smg Potassium, and %sg Protein" %(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]))
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
Type in the name of the sub sandwich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of:
bacon
282 Calories, 688.4g Fat, 420mg Sodium, 1407mg Potassium, and 33.5g Protein
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
Type in the name of the sub sandwich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of:
ham
192 Calories, 555.2g Fat, 340mg Sodium, 1802mg Potassium, and 44.3g Protein
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
Type in the name of the sub sandwich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of:
cheese
123 Calories, 558.9g Fat, 150mg Sodium, 1230mg Potassium, and 12.5g Protein
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: I must say splendid answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast a non number string as a float. Do it as follows:

```
sub = input("Type in the name of the sub sandwhich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of.")

if sub == 'bacon':     # 'bacon' not bacon 
    print("282 Calories, 688.4g Fat, 420mg Sodium, 1407mg Potassium, and 33.5g Protein")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a string, not a float number. Use input instead of float(input). And in the If statement, put in quotations for the bacon

```
sub = input("Type in the name of the sub sandwhich which you'd like to know the nutrition facts of.")

if sub == 'bacon': print("282 Calories, 688.4g Fat, 420mg Sodium, 1407mg Potassium, and 33.5g Protein")
```